# Does Minecraft need to unpack its launcher on every launch?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-launcher

I'm running Minecraft in a lab environment, with everyone's AppData on a network share. Minecraft (1.7.4, and launcher 1.3.9, currently, on XP) runs fine, but one part of the launching process seems odd to me:

When the bootstrapper runs, one of the steps is to check for updates to the main Launcher, download, then unzip the launcher.jar file. For us, this unpacking step happens on *every* launch -- even if there's already an up-to-date launcher.jar in the user's folder, it's deleted and a new one is unpacked in its place.

Is that normal? If not, got any ideas what might be causing it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes the "unpacking launcher" just means that the launcher is starting up. It happens every time.

Comment: So that's normal. Okay, thanks for verifying. Is strange, though, that it would delete/redownload/re-unpack a perfectly good .jar file on every launch. (On our slow network, the unpacking process can take upwards of five minutes, which is pretty rough.)

Answer (score -1):

Im having the same problem, but I don't think its normal. My laucher did not have to do that every time at first, but now it does. You may copy all of your data (world saves, settings etc.) at This pc > Local disk > Users > [User name] > *YOU NEED TO UNHIDE THIS FOLDER! TO CHECK HOW YOU NEED TO DO THIS, GO TO THIS LINK! https://www.sevenforums.com/tutorials/56005-file-folder-hide-unhide.html* AppData > *YOU NEED TO UNHIDE THIS FOLDER TOO* Roaming >.minecraft. The path for this all is [DRIVE LETTER]:\Users[USER NAME]\AppData\Roaming.minecraft . Copy all of this data. Then go to https://minecraft.net/ and download the laucher again. Before you run it, you need to make sure that minecraft is uninstalled. Just search uninstall in the windows search menu. That just reinstall the laucher, get all of the data back in the .minecraft folder, and **your done!**

Hope this helped!

Comment: The method that you proposed was neither true nor false, but the Question-Asker wanted to know whether the _Unpacking Of Archives on Every Launch_ was **normal**. The answer you provided was a 'How To', not a 'Yes it is normal / No it is not normal' answer.

Comment: Is this supposed to stop it from downloading every time? The purpose of this post could be [edit]ed to be more clear. It just says "I have this problem too. Do this. You're done! Hope this helped!" but it never says what it's supposed to help or why anyone should do it.